# How to get the frame of video at specific position continuously in Exoplayer

Tags: android, frame, preview, exoplayer

I have used this example for retrieving frames of video . Is there any way to get the frames of video continuously but this is not an appropriate example.
https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract images of certain frames programmatically?

Comment: I want to get frames of video like images to show in image view on seeking the seekbar programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This method should do the trick:

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri, long time) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    try {

        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time);

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            retriever.release();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: it will return null  ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of [orimen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691386/3305315).

```
exoPlayer.setVideoFrameMetadataListener((presentationTimeUs, releaseTimeNs, format, mediaFormat) -> currentFrame = getVideoFrame(getContext(), Uri.parse(data.path), presentationTimeUs));
```